# Updating a Gitlab repo with remote server directory which is not a repo

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab repo which is just a data store that should mirror the data stored in production in some directory. Gitlab has ssh credentials for said server.

I want to create a script that syncs the repo with the content of the directory (which is not a repo) using Gitlab pipelines every night. However, I am not sure about the workflow. Is there a less cumbersome way than using `rsync` to retrieve the data and have Gitlab commit and push the updated content to the master branch of the repo?

Comment: In what way using `rsync` is cumbersome? Especially considering that using it will be written in a script…

Comment: This is just the only workflow I came up with, asking whether there are more straightforward ones than using `rsync`, committing and pushing (which does not seem the cleanest solution as I would have to skip CI on the commits by Gitlab, allow Gitlab to push directly to master and what not).